# Word that means desired attributes

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Something like deserdia but google turns up nothing, means list of desired characteristics.

Comment: For anyone to provide an answer we need context. Please provide some background or idea of your intent.

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

Comment: It appears that she knows of the word, seems to realize that it would meet her needs if she knew how to spell it, but has only a very vague idea of how it's spelled. She's already decided what she wants; she's just looking for spelling. If we have a [tag:spelling] tag that would be more appropriate here, I think.

Comment: I'm not sure why there's so much fussing about my question. It was straightforward and I got my answer from @MattGutting. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean *desiderata*, singular [desideratum](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desiderata):

> something desired as essential

(Merriam-Webster)

Comment: As I said: "I think you mean ***desiderata***". Merriam-Webster only gives the definition in the singular.

Comment: Missed the unred part; sorry.

Answer (score 3):

*Desiderata*, Latin for "desired things", and the title of a famous poem that begins "Go placidly amid the noise and haste, and remember what peace there may be in silence..."

n .pl [Desiderata](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/desideratum) (sing. Desideratum):

> - Something considered necessary or highly desirable:
>
> "The point is not that the artist has 'penetrated the character' of his sitter, that commonplace desideratum of portraiture" (Robert Hughes).

Source: The American Heritage® Dictionary.